# Удалить элементы из одномерного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.x

Нужно решить задачу, у меня не выходит.

Дан одномерный список, содержащий `n` элементов. И нужно удалить `m` элементов из этого списка, начиная с позиции `k`.

Вот код, который я уже написал, но он не работает.

```
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
m=int(input())
k=int(input())
for i in range(k,k+m):
        a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

Comment: А можете показать ваши наработки, что вы уже сделали. За вас никто делать полностью не будет никто.

Comment: конечно,секунду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модифицировать список, который вы итерируете - очень плохая идея.
Почему бы просто не использовать срезы?

```
lst=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
start = 3
length = 4
del lst[start:start+length]
print(lst)
```

> [0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите преобразовать исходный список, используйте `del`

```
del a[k:k+m]
print(a)
```

А если хотите создать новый список, сохранив старый, то можно сделать 2 среза элементов от начала до позиции `k` и после позиции `k + m` до конца, а результаты объединить.

```
result = a[:k] + a[k+m:]
print(result)
```